# multivariate function prediction neural network in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, neural-network

I'm trying to us matlab ANN for predict T as a function of 5 variables,

```
T = f(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

and i assume that there is a linear function such as :

```
T = ax1 + bx2 + cx3 + dx4 + ex5
```

i want to find weight vector [a,b,c,d,e].

each training set is timeseries like:

```
t1,x11,x21,x31,x41,x51
t2,x12,x22,x32,x42,x52
......
......
......
......
......
tn,x1n,x2n,x3n,x4n,x5n
```

This training set is obtained from suing weight vector w1 i want to reform this vector so that my variables get close to :

```
X = [X1,X2,X3,X4,X5] (desire matrix)
```

exactly this is a control problem, buy using Wi vector i run my system(and control my T with : T = W*x) and grab new x vector(that is time sequence) and add this one to the training data and again run the algorithm.

Comment: Did you have a question? Where are you stuck? Have you written any code?

Comment: yes, but it not works, i dont know how should i do it

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about how to create a [mcve].